# Enable TIFF compression in Canon Digital Photo Professional 4

Tags: canon, image-compression, tiff, canon-dpp

I can't find a way to enable TIFF compression in the files produced by batch export in Canon Digital Photo Professional (currently version 4.2). This means that the generated TIFF files are far larger than I think they need to be. So I have a few questions on this subject:

- Is there any way to enable lossless TIFF compression in Canon Digital Photo Professional?
- If not, have Canon explained why they don't support TIFF compression?
- Do professional photographers tend to maintain their TIFF library without compression?

By the way, I'm talking about 8-bit TIFF files (because I keep the RAW originals alongside them). I have seen that [this quick test](http://www.luminescentphoto.com/blog/2012/11/30/a-quick-look-at-tiff-compression-options/) suggests that compression is actually pointless for 16-bit TIFF files.

Comment: Note that the save speed drops dramatically with compression. Could be a reason why it isn't implemented by DPP. Also, 8bit tiff doesn't really offer much over high quality jpeg.

Comment: @michael-clark: TIFF compression may be both lossless and lossy, JPEG is always (except when resaving image previously compressed with JPEG with optimisations) lossy. The raster JPEG image is just one of variety of data which may be stored using TIFF. In a way, TIFF is a container.

Comment: @MichaelClark, I'm not sure most of us would consider data loss or irreversibility  a _minute_ detail when it comes to compression algorithms, which is why TIFF typically use ZIP or LZW.

Comment: @inkista Although that was not exactly what I meant by the usage of the word *minute*, your point is well taken. I've deleted my comments and moved the one that should have been an answer to begin with to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to enable lossless TIFF compression in Canon Digital Photo Professional?

No.

> If not, have Canon explained why they don't support TIFF compression?

No.

> Do professional photographers tend to maintain their TIFF library without compression?

Most professional photographers I know save RAW files and the final file in whatever format they supply to the customer. Although TIFF was once a more common part of many pros' workflow, the ability of a multitude of photo applications to now work directly with native RAW files has enabled many to skip conversion to TIFF altogether. So most professionals I know do not maintain any sort of TIFF library at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone down-voted this answer.  I upvoted it to cancel the downvote.